# Form_for with url, format and html options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I feel like im missing something simple here. I am using the form_for helper with an object. I specify the url, the format, and html method. However, when rendered the url in the action attribute does not pick up the format. Here's my code:

```
=form_for(@site, url: compile_documents_path(@site), format: :csv, html: { method: :post}) do |f|
```

My controller is setup to respond to a csv format, and i simply call a to_csv method on the site object.

Any ideas as to why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Untested, but I think the format part should go into the url helper:

```
=form_for(@site, url: compile_documents_path(@site, format: :csv)) do |f|
```

Plus: I don't think you have to specify the `method: :post` part, as `form_for` will decide if it should use `PUT` or `POST`, based on whether @site is a new or an existing record.

Comment: Heh yep that did the trick. That came to mind, but i was trying to see if there was documentation on options for the dynamic methods created by the routes file. I guess I wasn't gutsy enough to just try.

Comment: This will not work for update action as you need singularize url `compile_document_path` not `compile_documents_path`.

Comment: @punitcse Depends on how the route is defined. Since agmcleod accepted the answer it seems to have worked for him. Also, you're commenting on a 7 year old answer. Rails changed a lot since then.