# is possible send more than one format in form_for helper rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-for

Is posible send more than one format, something like:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :format => :json, :csv, :xml) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't "send" a format, you send a request to the server, which responds to this request in the specified format. You can use a parameter to tell the controller which format you want it to return.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, can you write a example?. I use button_tag helper for button to submit form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "send a format", you send a request to the server, which responds to this request in the specified format. You can use a parameter to tell the controller which format you want it to return.

There are several ways to tell the controller which format you want. Actually there's only one way, passing a parameter, but there are several ways to pass this parameter.

I like the hidden_field method, in which you add a hidden field with the value being the format you want, and change the value of this field using javascript when a user selects a radio button with the format, for example. You can also do this using more than 1 submit button, and having the HTML onClick attribute set to a function that changes the value of the hidden_field.

Example (I'll use the multi-button method, and use jQuery):

First, let's build the form:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :format => :json, :csv, :xml) do |f| %>

...

<%= f.hidden_field :random_param_name, :value => "default format value" %>

// Notice you should use f.submit here instead of button_tag, because it's a form_for, not a form_tag

<%= f.submit "Give me XML!", :onClick => "changeFormat('xml');" %>
<%= f.submit "Give me JSON!", :onClick => "changeFormat('json');" %>
<%= f.submit "Give me CSV!", :onClick => "changeFormat('csv');" %>

<% end %>
```

Now we add the changeFormat function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFormat(format) {
        // The ID here is in the format "model_name_field_name". This is default for any form_for.
        $("#post_random_param_name").val(format);
    }
</script>
```

Now you just need to catch this parameter in the controller (`params[:post][:random_param_name]`) and do what you have to do! One last thing you need to do is adding this random_param_name to the accessible attributes of the Post model:

```
attr_accessor :random_param_name
attr_accessible :random_param_name
```

Comment: Thank you but I get syntax error with `:format => :json, :csv, :xml`.

Comment: Hmm, in which file are you writing this? You should choose only one format, use the parameter to choose.

Comment: And btw you're getting a syntax error because Ruby can't tell if the comma after :json is for separating the items of the array, like `:format => [:json, :csv, :xml]` or if it's separating parameters to a method, like `(:format => :json), (:csv), (:xml)`. To correct this ambiguity you should change to `:format => [:json, :csv, :xml]`, but it would still be wrong, because as I said, you can't return more than one format at the same response.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I faced the same problem, "how to send form with desired format".

So I'd found the solution and altered it. Instead of additional parameters I just replaced action attribute with needed URL, because [format is the part of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942326/form-for-with-url-format-and-html-options) (it is not the form attribute):

```
submit_tag "Get JSON", onClick: "$(this).closest('form').attr('action', '#{ my_path(format: :json) }')"
```

Therefore, you needn't to catch up parameters, use `respond_to` instead:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @my_object.to_hash }
  format.html
end
```

Hope it will be useful.