# Why Ajax call is responding after a page refresh in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have defined my create action like this:

```
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:appointment_id])
    @note = @appointment.notes.new(notes_params)
    @note.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save 
        format.html { redirect_to appointment_path(@appointment), notice: "Saved successfully" }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render 'new', notice: "Try again" }
        format.js
      end 
    end 
  end
```

My create.js.erb is like this:

```
$("#note_field").html("<%= j render partial: 'note', locals: {note: @note} %>");
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for([@appointment, @appointment.notes.build({user: current_user})], remote: true) do |f| %>

  <div>
    <% if @note && @note.errors.any? %>
      <% @note.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit class: "note-button" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here, note is partial form. How to make it work without a page refresh?

Comment: How are you making the ajax request? The should work as long as the request is made correctly.

Comment: what is you `form` code (create.html.erb)? maybe you need to add `remote: true` in your form tag

Comment: Check my edited post :)

Comment: youneed to specify the `format` in your `form_tag` like `format: js` (I never use format js only json like `format: json` ) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6942441/2144445